# Do credit card chargebacks apply to situations in which online retailer charges seller in favor of buyer?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, chargeback, online-retailer

This is the situation I have to deal with: One of the items I had listed with an online merchant sold. I shipped the item using standard postal service and provided buyer tracking information. A week after buyer filed a Guarantee Claim w/ online merchant claiming they never received the item. I responded to their claim that same day, providing additional information on the shipping.

Online retailer decided to refund buyer. I appealed the decision but they again decided again to refund buyer and charge my credit card.

It says on the tracking information that the item has been delivered. It is quite possible that the buyer has received the item. It is also quite possible that the item may have been stolen since many packages get stolen. I contacted the buyer asking if they have contacted the local post office asking for details, or if they have filed a police report. Buyer never responded.

I contacted the online merchant and told them I am open to any kind of investigation regarding what happened with the item. I asked them to tell me why my card is being charged and what I did wrong in the process. I also demanded a stay in the decision to charge my card.

They responded with:
"Although we understand your position, we stand by our decision.
We cannot give you more information about this matter, and we may not reply to further emails about this claim"

Would my credit card company reasonably take up a chargeback case? This is an unusual circumstance because I am not disputing a charge for a good/ service I never received. I am disputing a charge that comes after a decision to rule in favor of the buyer. I see the decision as unfair, I think I did everything according to the Terms and Conditions laid out by online retailer. Furthermore I tried several times to sort things out with the retailer they refused any kind of cooperation on this matter.

Comment: I don't understand how your credit card company would be involved in the transaction.

Comment: @quid when buyer made the purchase I got paid and I deposited the money into my bank account. Now for the refund, instead of charging my bank account, online retailer charged my credit card.

Comment: It's a lost cause. You basically agreed to all that when you signed the seller account agreement at Amazon.